# Problem with Favorites in Internet Explorer 8.0 on Windows 7

Tags: bookmarks

I go to a website.

I click on "Favorites," then "Add to Favorites."

Everyone knows that this should simply add the website to your Favorites list so you can access the website quicker in the future.

Here's the problem: often times, I'll add a website to the favorites and then it will add two icons of the website in the Favorites list.

But, only one icon actually links to the website. When I click on the other one, nothing happens (no matter how much I click on it).

Here's a picture of one of them:

[image: Problem with Favorites on Internet Explorer 8.0]

The mypay.dfas.mil-mypay.aspx will take me to the website. The bottom one will not.

Why is this happening?

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the properties of both shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/ie8-favorites-do-not-work/3555912d-abf1-44a3-93be-60bb55e03807) out. It says you might need to repair your installation, and provides a dowload script [here](http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&cat=42&id=133&artlang=en).  I haven't tried it myself, so please use it at your own risk.